# JavaScript's preventDefault method to stop password saving when form validation fails?

Tags: javascript, forms

I am fully against either dictating when a user can or can't save their passwords while I'm also against people dictating that `autocomplete` attribute support should be removed from rendering engines; it's always subjective to the situation at hand.

That being said I'm working on refining my password reset form and it's validation. When submitting the form the browser *always* attempts to update the password however if the form validation fails I do not want the browser to pester the person because obviously the password wasn't being updated if the form validation failed. I've attempted to use `event.preventDefault()` *just* for failed form validation however this doesn't seem to work in Firefox (my primary browser).

How can I stop the browser from prompting the user to save their password *only if* the form validation fails?

No frameworks or libraries.

Comment: Random string for the password name maybe? For example: `<input type="password" name="randomstring" />`. Maybe check the password with Ajax before submit is issued.

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing with this for my web app, and there's an interesting article on MDN concerning this subject.

[The autocomplete attribute and login fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

TL/DR: You can set the autocomplete attribute of the password node to 'new-password', and this will stop Firefox (at least) from offering to remember the password.

Good Luck...